# Save QGIS style created with espression string builder

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, rule-based

I created a rule-based renderer with espression string builder, where I also use the function editor in Python. When I share the style (qml) file with others, I realized that the Python function I wrote is not saved in the style file.

Is it possible to save the Python script inside the qml style file? And another question is, where are the Python script saved? I checked the usual pathes where QGIS stores script, but was not able to find it.

Comment: Ok, I found out that the python expressions are saved under user profile/python/expressions. So the remaining questions is how I can share the expressions with others, if possible through qml style file directly.